# Imprimir la primera posición de una letra en una cadena

Tags: dart

Tengo la siguiente tarea:

> Hacer un programa que Imprima carácter por carácter el contenido de una cadena cualquiera.
> Y también imprima la primera posición de la vocal a.
> Para ello deberás usar funciones para optimizar tu código.

Éste es el código que he hecho para la primera parte del problema (imprimir el contenido de la cadena carácter a carácter):

```
void main (){
  
  String cualquiera= "Ramos";

  for (int caracter in cualquiera.codeUnits) {
    print(String.fromCharCode(caracter));  
  }
}
```

Solo me falta imprimir la primera posición de la vocal "a". ¿Cómo podría hacer eso?

Comment: A que te refieres con imprimir la primera posición de la vocal a

Comment: Bienvenido RAMOS MANZANARES CHRISTIAN ALB a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

Es muy cómodo en estos casos, trabajar con un [Mapa](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.1/dart-core/Map-class.html).

```
void main (){
  
  String cualquiera= "Ramos";
 
  for (MapEntry e in cualquiera.split("").asMap().entries) {
    if (e.value == 'a') {
      print('La posición de la letra "${e.value}" es ${e.key}');
    }
    print("$e");
  }
  
}

MapEntry(0: R)
La posición de la letra "a" es 1
MapEntry(1: a)
MapEntry(2: m)
MapEntry(3: o)
MapEntry(4: s)
```

Lo que hacemos es: 1) convertir la cadena en una lista de caracteres con `split("")` y 2) con `AsMap()` transformamos cada elemento de la lista en una entrada del mapa dónde la clave es el índice o posición del caracter y el valor es el caracter en sí.

Answer (score 0):

En este caso la cadena puede ser tratada como un array, por lo tanto si deseas obtener el primer elemento de la cadena usa su indice:

```
  String cualquiera = 'Ramos';
  print('${cualquiera[0]}');
```

tendrìas como salida:

```
R
```

Por lo tanto para realizar:

> imprima la primera posición de la vocal a.

puedes realizarlo de esta forma:

```
   String cualquiera = 'Ramos';
 
  for (int i = 0; i < cualquiera.length; i++) {
     if(cualquiera[i] == "a"){
       print('la posiciòn de la primera "a" es ${i}');  
       break;
     }
     
  }
```

Salida:

```
la posiciòn de la primera "a" es 1
```

---

> Imprima carácter por carácter el contenido de una cadena cualquiera.

puedes iterar la cadena y puedes obtener caracter por caracter mediante su indice

```
  String cualquiera = 'Ramos';

  for (int i = 0; i < cualquiera.length; i++) {
    print('${cualquiera[i]}');
  }
```

Salida:

```
R
a
m
o
s
```

De hecho en este caso tambièn puedes hacer uso de [String.fromCharCode()](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.1/dart-core/String/String.fromCharCode.html) como lo muestras en tu pregunta:

```
  String cualquiera = 'Ramos';

  for (int caracter in cualquiera.codeUnits) {
    print(String.fromCharCode(caracter));  
  }
```

Salida:

```
R
a
m
o
s
```